# Curl of electric field is not zero in the case of a steady current in a loop

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, vectors

Say we got conducting circular loop connected to a battery . The electric field inside the loop  obeys equation $\vec{J}=\sigma \vec{E}$.

Since the current flows in a circumferential way around the loop the electric field will be circumferential as well which implies that the curl of the electric field will be non zero.
Which is a contradiction ,what's wrong in the above reasoning.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily see that for a stationnary circuit the curl of the electric field should be $0$ (as you mentionned, this comes from the Maxwell-Faraday equation).

However, this is not contradictory with the fact that $\overrightarrow{E}$ seems to be circumferential. $\overrightarrow{J}$ is indeed circumferential but $\overrightarrow{E}$ is not. That's because $\overrightarrow{J} = \sigma \overrightarrow{E}$ only holds in a ohmic conductor, and you must have a generator in your circuit (otherwise $\overrightarrow{J} = \overrightarrow{E} = \overrightarrow{0}$), and the electric field in your generator is actually opposite to the current, in such a way that $\int_C \overrightarrow{E} \cdot \overrightarrow{dl} = 0$ (so no contradiction with $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \times \overrightarrow{E} = \overrightarrow{0}$).

Comment: That resolves it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the curl of the electric field is not necessary to be zero in all cases. It's only valid for electrostatics.

Maxwell's equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) is valid through out the electrodynamics which given by :

$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$
$$\nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0$$
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\left(\mathbf{J}+\epsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\right)$$

Comment: The magnetic field is constant since the current is constant so the curl should be zero

Comment: Constant current wire also produces the magnetic field.

Comment: But constant magnetic field should not contribute to the curl of electric field, right?